# How to reload controls after disposing / removing them

Tags: c#, controls, dispose, reload

So I want to make a program that includes dynamic control layouts, kind of similar to a web page.
Theres a certain button that I have, if you click on it it is supposed to dispose all the current controls that can be seen and load a complete new set of controls with a second InitializeComponent.

The second page will include a "back" button that is supposed to dispose the second set of controls, and reload the original ones with the first InitializeComponent again so that I kind of have 2 different accesable "pages".

However, each time I switch via the button and call the InitializeComponent again, the VRAM usage will increase steadily probably because it doesnt really "kill" off all previous resources with dispose.

So I wanted to ask if there's a way to reload initialized controls that have been disposed without having to initialize them again.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
ahh nevermind, I got it.

instead of .dispose I just use the Controls.Remove command to remove the current set of controls when changing to page 2.
If i want to go back, I can now simple use the Controls.Add command to view the first set of controls again and VRAM usage does not increase.

This was not possible with dispose, anyone care to explain that? Im a REAL beginner in csharp, basically started a few days ago.

Comment: Are you removing event handlers from the controls before you remove them? That might explain the memory leak.

Comment: @Marco That's the wrong approach – just do that it show that is what is happening, then you know the GC will handle it (eventually). Only explicitly collect to control when collections happen in an application where it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not really supposed to call Dispose() yourself. Normally the framework will do that for you when you call Close() on a Form and such.
Apparently this does not always result in the respective element being removed if there are still references to it. This is the reason your controls where still there in a way.

If you (for some reason) need to Close() or Remove() and element for which you keep a reference you should do a element.IsDisposed check before doing anything else. If this is true you should create it anew because the element is half dead already. No necromancy, please :-)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Dispose` on any disposable object should cause it to release (set references to null) any referenced disposable objects, and clean up any directly referenced unmanaged resources. In the case of UI controls disposing will free up the unmanaged underlying Win32 GUI objects. Dispose is *not* about releasing memory for re-use, that's done by the garbage collector when objects are not referenced (indirectly) by some static or stack (local) reference. If you are keeping a reference to the last page (to go back to) then controls in its `Controls` collection will still be referenced and keeping them alive.

Even if they are removed from the controls collection and otherwise unreferenced, as UI controls tend to be around for a while it is likely that they have moved from generation zero (collected frequently) to generation 1 or even 2 (collected rarely). Unless there is memory pressure (your system doesn't have much free memory) it might be a long time before collecting them.

You can demonstate this by either using WinDbg with SOS extensions to look at what generation specific objects are in (or even list all objects in that generation), or by forcing a full collection.

Forcing a collection is *not* a real solution, but would demonstrate it is not a problem, they will be freed when the process needs free memory, then the garbage collector will do a full collection.